# Convert UDTT (User Defined Table Type) into string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible in SQL Server convert an UDTT (User Defined Table Type) into a some kind of string?

For example, If I have an UDTT with three columns: Id, Code and Description
could it be formatted into a string like below?

```
Id, Code, Description; Id, Code, Description;
```

and so on...

Function ToString() applied on UDTT is not working, for example:

```
SELECT myUDTT.ToString() as 'myUDTT_string'
```

is not working.

Comment: No you can't just call the ToString method of a table datatype to get this. Not sure why you would think it would just do this for you. In context of a select statement this just makes no sense at all. What are you really trying to do here? Why do you want a delimited list of values like this. Avoiding delimited lists is the whole reason user defined table types were created.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `CONCAT()` to concatenate the columns, and `STUFF()` to stuff them all into a single string? Though, as @SeanLange points out, I'm not sure why you'd want to. If we know what you're trying to achieve, there's likely a better way to do it than stuffing it all into a single string like that.

Comment: I have a store procedure and I pass as a parameter an UDTT. Within the store procedure I want to do a log into a log table. This log table contains the columns: Time at which store procedure was executed, name of the store procedure, parameters of the store procedure. So I want to convert the udtt passed as parameter into a some kind of delimited  list of values (into a single string) to store then in the log table. This is the reason I am trying to convert it into a single string.

Comment: Hm. You might want to consider storing it as XML rather than a string. Storing it as a single string in SQL makes it harder to parse. Storing it as XML makes it very easy to query if necessary.

Comment: @ZLK ok, storing it as xml instead of a string is ok for me so how can I convert it into an xml?

Comment: Well, it depends what you want the data to look like. For example, one way would be: `SELECT * FROM myUDTT FOR XML PATH('rowData');` which would produce something like `<rowData><Id>A</Id><Code>B</Code><Description>C</Description></rowData><rowData><Id>D</Id><Code>E</Code><Description>F</Description></rowData>` etc. But there's a variety of ways you could implement it, depending on how you want to work with the data once it's done.

Comment: And to query that, you might do something like `select a.b.value('ID[1]', 'INT') ID, a.b.value('Code[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') Code, a.b.value('Description[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') [Description] from myLogTable CROSS APPLY myLogColumn.nodes('rowData') a(b);`